# stop self.after when interrupt happens

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I started coding snake in python 3. As GUI i use Tkinter.
I got a timer which waits for a second an then calls the method again. Well now my question is how to i stop the `self.wait`?

I know i could work around this pretty easily, but i had this problem already somewhere else, so it would be nice to know how i can stop this.

This is the method which moves the snake around. (Only the timer is critical). The timer is here so it moves every second.

```py
   def move_snake(self):
        self.after(1000, self.move_snake)
        # code goes on
```

Now if i change the direction (by pressing a button) i do following:

```py
    def change_direction(self, event):
        self.pressed = event.keysym
        self.move_snake()
```

If i do this this way the "old" timer still is active and therefore the method gets called multiple times (it adds an additional timer when you press an button).

It would be nice that just the latest timer is activated.

Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `move_snake` uses `self.pressed`, you don't need to call `move_snake` inside of `change_direction`.

However, if you really want to stop the old loop and start a new loop, you can save the id that is returned from `after` and give that to `after_cancel`:

```
def move_snake(self):
    self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.move_snake)
    # code goes on

def change_direction(self, event):
    self.pressed = event.keysym

    # cancel the old loop
    self.after_cancel(self.after_id)

    # start a new loop
    self.move_snake()
```

Comment: i knew that i don't need to call move_snake inside change_direction but that wouldn't worked quite that well. (could have also done with a bool but again thats not beautiful). but thanks anyway. was exactly what i needed